# Prestashop API to users manage it's shopping

Tags: api, rest, prestashop-1.6

I have been studying the API Web Service that Prestahop offers, but this API can only be used for manage the shop, not for the users login and buy items , check it's accounts, etc.

Exist some API in which you can get an access token for authentication to use in the API calls and buy items, check account state, find products, etc to use for example to make an app for the shop.

Thanks in advance.